# How do I set the start time to run in 5 mins right after task is created for the following code instead of a specific time?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

How do I set the start time to run in 5 mins right after task is created for the following code instead of a specific time?

```
c:
schtasks /create /tn "DAILYPROCCOMPLETE" /tr "\\server\Digital Imaging\Batch Programs\DAILYPROCCOMPLETE.bat" /sc once /s COMPUTER /u DOMAIN\USER /p PASSWORD /st 20:00 /f
```

Comment: `/DELAY 05:00`?

Comment: Hi David, /delay is only valid for schedule types "onstart, onlogon, or onevent".  Is there a solution for schedule type "once"?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

I had to create a powershell script and saved the ps1 file to a mapped drive J:\MyJobs\Dailyrun\createtask-it03-pfcmaster.ps1 with the following code:

```
$time = [DateTime]::Now.AddMinutes(5)
$hourMinute=$time.ToString("HH:mm")
schtasks.exe /create /tn "DAILYPROCCOMPLETE" /tr "\\pfcoffice3\Digital Imaging\Batch Programs\DAILYPROCCOMPLETE.bat" /sc once /s SYSTEMNAME /u DOMAIN\USER /p PASSWORD /st $hourMinute /f
```

Then my bat file runs it with the following code:

```
@echo off
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File J:\MyJobs\Dailyrun\createtask-it03-pfcmaster.ps1
```